# AS3 bingo game - is it possible?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, random

I'm at a complete loss.

I'm trying to generate random Bingo tickets, but I'm stuck right now.
The point is, that have the following code:

```
var startNum:Number = 1;
var endNum:Number = 90;
var rp:RandomPlus = new RandomPlus(endNum, startNum);

var variant_1:Array = new Array
                    (rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), 
                     "", "",  "", "",  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

var variant_2:Array = new Array
                    (rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), 
                     "", "",  "", "",  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

var variant_3:Array = new Array
                    (rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), 
                     "", "",  "", "",  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

var variant_4:Array = new Array
                    (rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), 
                     "", "",  "", "",  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

var variant_5:Array = new Array
                    (rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), 
                     "", "",  "", "",  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

var variant_6:Array = new Array
                    (rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), rp.getNum(), 
                     "", "",  "", "",  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");



function shuffle(a, b):Number {
    var num:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*2)-2;
    return num;
}


var b:Array = variant_1.sort(shuffle);
var cnt:uint=0;
for (var i = 0; i<b.length/9; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j<b.length/3; j++) {
        var grid1:box=new box();
        grid1.x=5+(grid1.width-1)*j;
        grid1.y=5+(grid1.height-1)*i;
        grid1.txt.text=b[cnt];
        addChild(grid1);
        cnt++;
    }
}

var c:Array = variant_2.sort(shuffle);
var cnt2:uint=0;
for (var k = 0; k<c.length/3; k++) {
    for (var l = 0; l<c.length/9; l++) {
        var grid2:box=new box();
        grid2.x=5+(grid2.width-1)*k;
        grid2.y=100+(grid2.height-1)*l;
        grid2.txt.text=c[cnt2];
        addChild(grid2);
        cnt2++;
    }
}

var d:Array = variant_3.sort(shuffle);
var cnt3:uint=0;
for (var m = 0; m<d.length/3; m++) {
    for (var n = 0; n<d.length/9; n++) {
        var grid3:box=new box();
        grid3.x=5+(grid3.width-1)*m;
        grid3.y=200+(grid3.height-1)*n;
        grid3.txt.text=d[cnt3];
        addChild(grid3);
        cnt3++;
    }
}

var e:Array = variant_4.sort(shuffle);
var cnt4:uint=0;
for (var o = 0; o<e.length/3; o++) {
    for (var p = 0; p<e.length/9; p++) {
        var grid4:box=new box();
        grid4.x=5+(grid4.width-1)*o;
        grid4.y=300+(grid4.height-1)*p;
        grid4.txt.text=e[cnt4];
        addChild(grid4);
        cnt4++;
    }
}

var f:Array = variant_5.sort(shuffle);
var cnt5:uint=0;
for (var q = 0; q<f.length/3; q++) {
    for (var r = 0; r<f.length/9; r++) {
        var grid5:box=new box();
        grid5.x=5+(grid5.width-1)*q;
        grid5.y=400+(grid5.height-1)*r;
        grid5.txt.text=f[cnt5];
        addChild(grid5);
        cnt5++;
    }
}

var g:Array = variant_6.sort(shuffle);
var cnt6:uint=0;
for (var s = 0; s<g.length/3; s++) {
    for (var t = 0; t<g.length/9; t++) {
        var grid6:box=new box();
        grid6.x=5+(grid6.width-1)*s;
        grid6.y=500+(grid6.height-1)*t;
        grid6.txt.text=g[cnt6];
        addChild(grid6);
        cnt6++;
    }
}
```

Which outputs this:

[image: Bingo]
As you can see, I've got 162 cells divided into 9x3 tables. Each table contains 15 numbers and 12 empty spaces. All the numbers are between 1-90 and do not repeat. The positions of the numbers are random.

The real problem is that I have to conform to a few rules:

- The sum of the numbers in each table is equal.
- There are 9 columns, which must be arranged like so: first column 1-9, second column 10-19, third column 20-29, ... , ninth column 80-90.
- Each row has 4 spaces.

What now? It seems impossible.

Comment: All you need is more math in your logic, and maybe some backtracking.

Comment: Any idea where to start?

Comment: Hm, I don't quite understand the middle requirement. Are you saying that the first column in each table can only contain the numbers 1 to 9? If so, there are 6 tables, where collectively the first column has 18 spaces. I don't see how you can fit the numbers 1-9 without repeats.

Comment: Look at it as a big 9x18 table split into six 9x3 tables.

Answer (score 1):

You really should improve your code. You don't need a variable to each variant, you can do that using an bidimensional array. Something like this:

```
var tables:Array = new Array();

for(var i:uint = 0; i <= 6; 6++){
    tables[i] = fillTable();
    drawTables(tables);
}

...

function fillTable():Array{
    var emptySpaces:Array = new Array();
    var tableData:Array   = new Array();
    emptySpaces = getRandomElements(); //this function should return an array which will represent all 12 empty spaces, otherwise, 12 numbers between 0 and 26

   for (var i = 0; i <= 27; i++) {
       if(emptySpaces.indexOf(i) < 0){ // if my current i isn't a empty space I give it a value
           tableData[i] = generateRandomBasedOnIndex(i);
       }
   }
}

function generateRandomBasedOnIndex(i):uint{
    var maxInt = (i+1) * 10 - 1;
    var minInt = Math.abs(maxInt + 1 - 9);

    return new RandomPlus(maxInt, minInt).getNum();
}

function getRandomElements():Array{
    // TODO - homework :)
}

function drawTables(tableData:Array):void{
    // just use tableData array to place yours display objects on Stage
}
```

Why do you need to the sum of all number to be equal on tables? This is an rule? I don't think this happens in real life bingos.

Ps.: I don't have any ActionScript editor here, so you may find some syntax error, but give a good look in these lines, I think that logic should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have to make a game to which we have no sources, and I have noticed this pattern (the sum) for each new ticket.

Comment: For the sake of your accomplishment I'd suggest you to you avoid, or at least let this feature to the end.

Comment: So you're telling me not to use this feature?

Comment: Upon another look, it was an incredible coincidence that two of the tables had equal sums, but apparently, it's not a rule.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, getRandomElements returns either the 12 empty spaces in a variant or 12 numbers between 0 and 26? So it would be if (something) -> array = 12 * "" -> else random(0-26)?

Comment: @AlexGorcea It should return 12 values, each value having a unique value between 0 and 26.   I've made it using JS, try translating it to AS3 (http://jsfiddle.net/DZmGY/1/), just ask me if you have any question.

Comment: Hm... tableData outputs some strange patterns: 3,17,25,16,21,13,8,18,0,9,12,10
3,17,25,16,21,13,8,18,0,9,12,10,13,15,19,17,2,12,14,11,24,1,21,16
3,17,25,16,21,13,8,18,0,9,12,10,13,15,19,17,2,12,14,11,24,1,21,16,15,16,7,23,17,3,1,20,10,8,25,4
3,17,25,16,21,13,8,18,0,9,12,10,13,15,19,17,2,12,14,11,24,1,21,16,15,16,7,23,17,3,1,20,10,8,25,4,18,26,17,22,6,13,25,11,9,4,1,16...